# Linq2XML missing element

Tags: asp.net, xml, linq

How do I modify the query below to properly handle the case where the "Summary" element is missing from one of the articles?  Now when that happens I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
var articles = from article in xmlDoc.Descendants("Article")
        select new {
            articleId = article.Attribute("ID").Value,
            heading = article.Element("Heading").Value,
            summary = article.Element("Summary").Value,
            contents = article.Element("Contents").Value,
            cats = from cat in article.Elements("Categories")
            select new {
                 category = cat.Element("Category").Value
            }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `article.Element("Summary")` returns `null` if the element is not found, so you get a `NullReferenceException` when you try to get the Value property.

To solve this, note that `XElement` also has an [explicit conversion to `string`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155263.aspx). This won't throw if the `XElement` is `null` - you will just get a `null` string reference.

So to solve your problem you can change this:

```
summary = article.Element("Summary").Value,
```

to this:

```
summary = (string)article.Element("Summary")
```